# Boot in virtual console mode with full resolution

Tags: 12.04, boot, grub2, virtual-console, framebuffer

I am able to either:

1) Boot into X, switch to virtual console #1 and use it at full resolution

or

2) Boot into virtual console mode -only and use them with 80 columns max

How can I boot into virtual console mode and use the maximum framebuffer resolution?